# Does INTERLEAVE support the transitive property?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Lets say I have three tables, `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz`

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
FooId BYTES(MAX)
) PRIMARY KEY (FooId);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Bar (
FooId BYTES(MAX),
BarId BYTES(MAX)
) PRIMARY KEY (FooId, BarId),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Foo on DELETE CASCADE;
```

```
CREATE TABLE Baz (
FooId BYTES(MAX),
BazId BYTES(MAX)
) PRIMARY KEY (FooId, BazId),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Foo on DELETE CASCADE;
```

This diagram demonstrates the `INTERLEAVE` hierarchy:

```
+-----+   +-----+
|     |   |     |
| Foo <---+ Bar |
|     |   |     |
+--^--+   +-----+
   |
+--+--+
|     |
| Baz |
|     |
+-----+
```

[Cloud Spanner's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#database-splits) Describes `INTERLEAVE` as

> You can define hierarchies of parent-child relationships between tables up to seven layers deep, which means you can co-locate rows of seven logically independent tables.

Since we used `INTERLEAVE` between `Bar` and `Foo`, I believe we're guaranteed that they are co-located, with the same keys. Just like how we `INTERLEAVE` `Baz` and `Bar`, they should be co-located as well, with the same keys.

If that's true, then are we guaranteed that `Bar` and `Baz` are co-located, with the same keys, as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scenario described, Bar and Baz are collocated (or in the same split) given a FooId key. Within a split, the rows from each table are grouped together.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. This knowledge makes it much easier to design a schema now